# Getting an error when trying to set new max

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program at the minute has to get the data from a CSV text file which I have got working, but when I try to set the max to the distance[counter] I get an error which states:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

I understand this, but I'm struggling to get it to work.

```
forename = [""] * 100
surname = [""] * 100
distance = [0.0] * 100


# Gets the members details from the file

#strip the file by /n to get seperate lines

# split it by commas to get each value in each line

def get_members_info():
    counter = 0
    with open("members.txt",'r') as readfile:
        line = readfile.readline().rstrip('/n')
        while line:
            items = line.split(",")
            forename[counter] = items[0]
            surname[counter] = items[1]
            distance[counter] = items[2]

            line = readfile.readline().rstrip('/n')
            counter +=1
    return forename, surname, distance
#
def print_max_distance(forename, surname, distance):
    maximum = 0.0
    print (distance[0])
    for counter in range (1, len(distance)):
        if distance[counter] > maximum:
            maxs = distance[counter]
            print (maxs)
    print (maxs)

#
get_members_info()
print_max_distance(forename, surname, distance)
```

Comment: Which line is failing? `distance[counter] = items[2]` this one?

Comment: `distance[counter]` is str. The check with `maximum` hence fails. Probably `distance[counter] = float(items[2])` helps, but not when `items[2]` is a non digit.

Comment: this line  if float(distance[counter]) > maximum:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line` is a string so when you split it you get a list of strings. You then try to compare on of these strings with a float which fails.

If you can guarantee that the distance is always a number than you can simply replace `distance[counter] = items[2]` with `distance[counter] = float(items[2])`